# Aggregate values based on categories and subcategories

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to create a document which automatically tracks spending based on two categories.

For example, I have a sheet formatted similar to the table below:

```
Type    |   Amount  |   Category  
Visa    |   $100    |   Hair  
Chase   |   $200    |   Face  
Visa    |   $50     |   Hair  
Master  |   $150    |   Face  
Visa    |   $25     |   Face
```

And my goal is to update a seperate table with spending broken down for both "Type" and "Category", like this:

```
        |   Total  |   Hair  |   Face   |   Mouth
Total   |   $525   |   $150  |   $375   |   $0   
Visa    |   $175   |   $150  |   $25    |   $0   
Chase   |   $200   |   $0    |   $200   |   $0   
Transfr |   $0     |   $0    |   $0     |   $0   
Master  |   $150   |   $0    |   $150   |   $0
```

Note: all categories in the above table are intended to be static with only their relevant values getting filled in. That's why "Mouth" and "Transfr" are part of the table, even though they have no transactions in that category.

I have attempted to use the "Query" formula but I am only able to sort based on one category receiving results like these:

```
        |   Sum
Visa    |   $175  
Chase   |   $200 
Transfr |   $0   
Master  |   $150
```

or

```
        |   Sum
Hair    |   $300  
Face    |   $225
```

I am not sure if this is possible on Google Sheets, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To sort the QUERY result, use the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: i]

- **C11**: **`=SUM(C3:C9)`**
- **C12**: **`=IFERROR(SUM(QUERY($B$3:$D$9,"select C where B='"&$B12&"'")),0)`**
- **D11**: **`=IFERROR(SUM(QUERY($B$3:$D$9,"select C where D='"&D$10&"'")),0)`**
- **D12**: **`=IFERROR(SUM(QUERY($B$3:$D$9,"select C where B='"&$B12&"' and D='"&D$10&"'")),0)`**
- **F15**: **`=IFERROR(SUM(QUERY($B$3:$D$9,"select C where B='"&$B15&"' and D='"&F$10&"'")),0)`**
- etc.

## **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kmP4wq9HxTyS474e6isDnfVQffbBh1XG-urBcbHMzJU/edit?usp=sharing)**

Comment: Yes! This worked, thank you very much